# Jekyll render same template in multiple languages

Tags: html, templates, jekyll, multilingual

I have a template page with a number of labels.  I would like to produce several html's from this template, say one per each language. Is this possible using Jekyll?
I have seen a multi-language-plugin, however it seems not working anymore.
Can Jekyll produce more pages from a single template?
If the answer is negative, do you know any other static site generator that can handle multi language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good way to implement multi-language sites in Jekyll is via [jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin](https://github.com/Anthony-Gaudino/jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin) that also works with Jekyll v3.x

You can find an useful tutorials on how to install and configure the plugin [here](http://jekyll-langs.liaohuqiu.net/) and [here](http://www.klaasnotfound.com/2017/02/16/proper-multilingual-site-with-github-pages-and-jekyll/).

As an alternative, you can try to implement multi-language without any plugin, using [this tutorial](https://www.sylvaindurand.org/making-jekyll-multilingual/).

Comment: Thank you. I will accept this answer, however there is a great problem with it: you always have to create a different file for each page. If I have 10 pages, and 10 languages, I have to manually create 100 different files. This is not really portable.